# How to store a 2D array in a stack of different types?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to teach myself Java and I came across some practice problems on YouTube. I've managed to make it to the stack chapter and now I'm stuck. I've created a baseball draft class and now I need to have a class to store the player information.  Is it possible to store an array in a stack containing two different types ? A stack that pushes string,int at each instance?

"Sam", 24
"Reynolds," 30
"Walker", 41

I need to place the information above in the stack. Suggestions? Please don't just post the answer code, that wouldn't be helpful

Comment: Why not make an object to encapsulate the information?

Comment: just create the class with string and int as data member. and push that object into the stack. something like this Class playerinformation { String name ; int age} and create the object of playerinformation and push  it into the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zong Zheng Li suggested, you could create a new class that has 2 member variables.

```
public class Player{

    String name;
    int age; //I'm not sure what the integer is supposed to represent

    //constructor
    Player(String playerName, int playerAge){
        this.name = playerName;
        this.age = playerAge;
    }

    //getters
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;    
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;    
    }

}
```

Then you can create player objects with the values you need using the new keyword

```
Player sam = new Player("Sam", 24);
```

and then add the players to the stack

```
stack.push(sam);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store an array like ["Sam", 24 "Reynolds," 30 "Walker", 41], you can create array as Object. By this way you can store any kind of type. Also, when you want to take data like stack you can start reading data at the end of the array.